# Get files from form without querying for input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm trying to upload files using AJAX. However, I'm having issues grabbing the files from my form. I want to gather all the

```
<input type="file">
```

fields that are nested within the form, without using their specific ids. So, **not** like this:

```
console.log($( "#i_dont_want_to_query_for_this_id" )[0].files);
//FileList {0: File, length: 1}
```

I feel there must a be way to get them from the form element itself:

```
<form class="part-form">
  ...
  <input type="file" id="i_dont_want_to_query_for_this_id">
</form>
```

This is how I handle the submit:

```
$( ".part-form" ).each(function () {
        var $me = $( this );
        $me.on('submit', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var formElement = $me[0];
            var fd = new FormData(formElement);
            ...
 }
```

I guess this can also be achieved using classes and `each()` on these, but I feel there must be a way to grab all files in a submitted form by simply using the data in the form itself, I just cannot find it.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Firstly you need to give the `input` elements all `name` attributes otherwise they are invalid. To solve your issue, you can select them by class/name/type/any other attribute you want instead of `id`

Comment: They do have names, I should have kept that in in my examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an attribute selector like `$("file[type=input]")` to get all the file inputs. Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/don01001100/vmzhvbb0/2/).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( ".part-form" ).each(function () {
          var $me = $( this );
          $me.on('submit', function (event) {
              event.preventDefault();
              var $resultDiv = $("#result-div");
              $me.find("input[type=file]").each(function(index, fileInput) {
                  for(var i = 0; i < fileInput.files.length; i++) {
                      // Do whatever you really want to do with the file.
                      var $span = $("<span />");
                      $span.text(fileInput.files[i].name);
                      $resultDiv.append($span);
                  }
              })
          });
     });
})
```

Comment: Ye, this is what I will end up doing. I was just hoping that the form magically contained the files that were selected. It must be that the input owns the file - and not its parent form.

Comment: `It must be that the input owns the file - and not its parent form` that's correct. The files are only accessible through the `files` array on the input itself

Comment: That is my understanding. The file contents are only available through the `files` property. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList. If you don't mind, feel free to check this as your accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use can use selector  **$("input[type='file']")**

```js
$(document).on('change', 'input[type="file"]', function(){

  console.log($(this)[0].files)
  alert($(this)[0].files)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="part-form">
  ...
  <input type="file" id="i_dont_want_to_query_for_this_id">
  
  <input type="file" id="i_dont_want_to_query_for_this_id2">
</form>
```